# Find div class name from ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax response which is generated by a server sided script:

```
<div class="item-title3">Testname</div>
<div class="item-level">120</div>
<div class="item-binding">40</div>
<div class="item-type">Feet</div>
```

Now I want to get the `div class name` which contains the `item-title` word inside of the class name.  So the number in the div class name shouldn´t be relevant (in this case the 3 of item-title3 shouldn´t be relevant).

In this example I want to find and store `item-title3` inside my variable className.

I tried it with the filter method, but I get [object Object] as a result:

```
let className = $content.filter('div.item-title');
```

**Complete code:**

```
<script language="javascript">

jQuery(function($) {
  
  $("[tooltip-link]").each(function() {
    let $tooltip = $(this);
    let id = $tooltip.attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/datenbank/itemscript.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        "var": id
      }
    }).then(function(data) {

      let $content = $(data);
      let title = $content.siblings('[class^=item-title]').text()

     let className = $content.filter('div.item-title'); 
      
     
      $tooltip.tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "test",
        content: data
      });

       $("<div class=\"" + ClassName + "\">" + title + "</div>").appendTo($tooltip);
    });
  });
    
});
</script>

<a tooltip-link data-id="12555" title=""></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the element its class contains `item-title` you can use

```
var item_title = $('div[class*="item-title"]'); // select any div element has a class contains `item-title`
```

To get the class name you need *even if there're another classes for the same element* you can use `.split()` , `.indexOf`

See the next example

```js
var item_title = $('div[class*="item-title"]');
//console.log(item_title);
var ClassName = '';
var classes = item_title.attr('class').split(/(\s+)/); // split classes with space
$.each(classes , function(i , v){
  v = v.trim();  // trim() to avoid any left/right white-spaces 
  if(v.indexOf('item-title') > -1){  // if the class contains item-title
    ClassName = v; 
  }
});

console.log(ClassName);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-testClass  item-title3">Testname</div>
<div class="item-level">120</div>
<div class="item-binding">40</div>
<div class="item-type">Feet</div>
```

<sup>I added `item-testClass` class to the div element to check that the code works even there're another classes for the same element .. you can remove it</sup>

If you've more than one element with `item-title` and needs to get all of them use `.each`

```js
var item_title = $('div[class*="item-title"]'); // if its array of elements
//console.log(item_title);


item_title.each(function(){
  var ClassName = '';
  var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/(\s+)/); // split classes with space
  $.each(classes , function(i , v){
    v = v.trim();  // trim() to avoid any left/right white-spaces 
    if(v.indexOf('item-title') > -1){  // if the class contains item-title
      ClassName = v; 
    }
  });

  console.log(ClassName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-testClass  item-title3">Testname 3</div>
<div class="item-level">120</div>
<div class="item-binding">40</div>
<div class="item-type">Feet</div>
<div class="item-testClass  item-title50">Testname 50</div>
```